# Why toggling doesn't work on Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, devtools

I don't know why my javascript code is not toggling on firefox developers tools, and that's my code:

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.header .nav-bar .nav-list .hamburger');
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector('.header .nav-bar .nav-list .menu');
const header = document.querySelector('.header-container')

hamburger.addEventListener('click',() => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you've executed the posted code in developer tools _an even number of times_ trying to get it work? For more help try adding sufficient information (such as some HTML) for readers to [test the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check, if your element is clicked or not with console.log()

```
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log("test")
})
```

I suggest you not to use arrow function in addEventListener, because of 'this' problem in arrow function

Answer (score 0):

When you open developer tools in Firefox, on the left hand side of the menu  there are tab header for "inspect", "console", network" and so on.

On the right hand side of the same menu bar, there is an icon of a framed document that shows "Select an iframe as the currently targeted document" when you hover over it. Click the icon and select the iframe containing the `.header-container` element.

Assuming the correct nested elements have been set up in HTML, the posted code now runs if you paste it after the script input prompt and press enter, and you can click the hamburger icon to toggle its `active` cf class.

Use of the `const` declaration in the pasted script prevents it being run more than once without reloading the page, which is a good thing - an even number of anonymous listeners that each toggle `active` would not affect the class list of the hamburger element.

---

FWIW, some HTML that can be used to show the code in the post "just works" when run in the Firefox console:

```html
<style>
  div { margin: 0.5rem;  margin-left: 2rem; border: thin solid maroon;}
  .active {background-color: yellow;}
</style>

<div class="header-container">
  .header-container
  <div class="header">
    .header
    <div class="nav-bar">
       .nav-bar
       <div class="nav-list">
          .nav-list
          <div class="hamburger">
             .hamburger
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
             .menu
          </div>
          (nav-list)
        </div>
        (nav-bar)
      </div>
    (header)
  </div>
  (header-container)
</div>
```

*However*, if the hamburger menu structure is inside an iframe element it needs to be selected first to prevent generating an error that `hamburger` is `null`.